# binary division $11010 \div 100$?

Tags: binary, binary-operations

I'm trying to calculate binary division of $11010 \div 100$.

I got an answer $11.1$ which is wrong? Apparently I need to get $6.5$ (i.e $110.1$) as the answer. Can you anyone tell me how?

Comment: You can do long division,  it's the same as decimal. Or just do like usual 11010/100 = 110.1

Comment: I've done it. I'm getting $11.1$ as the answer.

Comment: Even if you didn't want to use long division, you could just slide the decimal point two places to the left since you are dividing by a power of the base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I get from long division:

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
                110.1  \\[-3pt]
100 \enclose{longdiv}{11010.0} \\[-3pt]
     \underline{100}\phantom{00.0} \\[-3pt]
                 101 \phantom{0.0} \\[-3pt]
      \underline{101}\phantom{0.0} \\[-3pt]
                   100 \phantom{.} \\[-3pt]
        \underline{100}\phantom{.}
\end{array}
$$

How did you do it?

If you still think it should be done differently, you can click "edit" under my answer to see how I formatted the long division procedure, and then you can "edit" something like that (but altered to show your own steps) into your question.

Alternatively, when I learned long division with decimal numbers, I learned you could save some trouble by discarding zeros at the end of the divisor and shifting the decimal point the same number of places left.
For example, to do $92566 \div 400$ it is sufficient to find $925{\color{red}{\mathbf .}}66 \div 4$.
This applies equally well in any other base; in your problem, we find that

$$11010 \div 100 = 110{\color{red}{\mathbf .}}10 \div 1, $$

and now you don't need to set up the long division at all.

Answer (score 1):

On *any* base, if the last digit of the numerator is $0$ and the denominator is $10$, the quotient is the numerator minus that final digit.

Comment: I'm sorry a small mistake in my question. It's suppose to be 11010 $\div$ 100

Comment: It is very anappropriate to change a question after an answer to the original question has been posted.